# dynamically creating function with promise infinite loop mocha

Tags: javascript, recursion, promise

8 hours later....

Not sure what happened, but I realized then when I wrote a file to the root directory of the project, it got stuck in an infinite loop. Anywhere else, it worked fine.

//UPDATE

Still working on this. Missed the superbowl. The only update I have is that writeFileSync gives the exact same error.

I've been banging my head on this one for a while now.

```
promiseFunction = [promiseFunction1, promiseFunction2, promiseFunction3].reduce((oldFunction, newFunction)=>{
 return function (){
  return oldFunction().then(()=>{
   return newFunction()
   })
  }
 }
```

when I try to test promiseFunction(), I get an infinite test loop (all of my tests up to the test promiseFunction keep firing in perpetuity)

The catch however, is that the promise function screwing it all up is `promisify(fs.writeFile)`

When I try using a different promise function, like `promisify(fs.readFile)`,
everything works fine.

When I console log the difference between the readFile and writeFile promises, there are the respective results:

```
//readFile

    readFilePromise Promise {
  _bitField: 67108864,
  _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
  _rejectionHandler0: 
   Promise {
     _bitField: 0,
     _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
     _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
     _promise0: undefined,
     _receiver0: undefined },
  _promise0: undefined,
  _receiver0: undefined }

//writeFile

   writeFilePromise Promise {
  _bitField: 67108864,
  _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
  _rejectionHandler0: 
   Promise {
     _bitField: 0,
     _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
     _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
     _promise0: undefined,
     _receiver0: undefined },
  _promise0: undefined,
  _receiver0: undefined }
```

I simply do not understand why I am getting this infinite loop with writeFile. Please god help.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is a series then perhaps returning a function is not what you want. Mainly because nothing is going to be called. Instead leverage the promise chaining:

```
[promiseFunction1, promiseFunction2, promiseFunction3]
  .reduce((memo, next) => memo.then(next), Promise.resolve());
```

Comment: the problem is that I then call the function for each object in an array I'm building